# TypeError: numpy.dtype[datetime64] and float64 problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to learn random forest,
I did this

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth = 2, random_state = 100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8449523b1c17> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth = 2, random_state = 100)
----> 4 rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in result_type(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[object_]'>)
```

Not sure how to convert to float or solve this error

I tried this:

```
X = df.values.astype("float64")
y = df.values.astype("float64")
```

But this error happened:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6f079ed1ed30> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 X = df.values.astype("float64")
      2 y = df.values.astype("float64")

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: Can you provide a [example]? Because, for example, where `X_train` and `y_train` are defined?